# Encoding Public Keys

Tags: public-key, ed25519, encoding

We would like to encode ECDSA Public Key specifically keys generated using the ed25519 for storage .

What is the best and less error prone method , for now we think about using Hex strings or Base64 are there other encoding schemes that can be used ?

Comment: Hey can you make a sample for education purpose how to encode a bitcoin public key to base64 or hex by python ? TY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, there are many ways. For instance, if you need to enter key manually, you may even prefer to split text representation into groups of 4 or more characters.

But I'd suggest you choose between **SSH2 (RFC 4716)** and **OpenSSH** format. Both use Base64 for key representation. Both have an advantage that they are supported by standard tools like ssh-keygen.

If you have multiple keys and want to more reliably distinguish them, I'd suggest **SSH2 (RFC 4716)**, because it provides slightly better possibilities to comment.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different ways you could encode, but unless you are really sensitive to the length of the encoding, in my experience just going with Base64 is a good idea. Support for Base64 is pretty ubiquitous. However, there are different variants of Base64 (URL-safe vs. standard), which complicates things if you are exchanging the encoded keys with someone else. Make sure you specify your choice (like URL-safe base64 without padding - RFC7515).